# Paradox of Field & Integral Domain in Venn Diagram

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Check out venn diagram from this [*link*](https://www.google.com/search?q=venn%20diagram%20numbers%20sets&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&imgil=xePFwYWbDP6IRM%253A%253BMQt8mZI0z2IRxM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fthinkzone.wlonk.com%25252FNumbers%25252FNumberSets.htm&source=iu&pf=m&fir=xePFwYWbDP6IRM%253A%252CMQt8mZI0z2IRxM%252C_&usg=__AHVtg5Hz9gGFON7am6y4NkTzOag%3D&biw=1280&bih=685&ved=0CCsQyjc&ei=YA28VPaUE-SCsQS0nIDoDg#imgdii=_&imgrc=xePFwYWbDP6IRM%253A%3BMQt8mZI0z2IRxM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fthinkzone.wlonk.com%252FNumbers%252FRealSet-big.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fthinkzone.wlonk.com%252FNumbers%252FNumberSets.htm%3B938%3B708), which is the order of number systems that has been embedded in my mind since grade school. Notice here that the integer $\mathbb Z$ is "inside" the rational number $\mathbb Q$.

But when I started learning ring theory couple of years ago, the order got upside-down: Check out diagram from this [*link*](https://www.google.com/search?q=venn%20diagram%20abstract%20algebra&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=OAy8VKWoHLeasQSrgYGgDg&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg&biw=1280&bih=685#tbm=isch&q=venn%20diagram%20ring%20theory&imgdii=_&imgrc=mMLj7NOL7LxFGM%253A%3BrbdSm1stqu4P7M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Frip94550.files.wordpress.com%252F2012%252F07%252Frings-7-2-1.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Frip94550.wordpress.com%252F2012%252F07%252F02%252Fintroduction-to-rings%252F%3B386%3B388), which is a typical venn diagram of rings. Notice that the ring of field is "inside" the integral domain, and remember that rational number $\mathbb Q$ is the most common example of field, and that integer $\mathbb Z$ is example of integral domain.

I always thought that abstract algebra is a generalization of number systems, but why is this paradox here? Thank you for your time.

Comment: The fifth amendment is a single law inside the US constitution, but constitutions of all countries are a subset of all laws. Is this a paradox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, any integral domain can be extended to a field of fractions containing an embedding of the original integral domain.

This is due to the fact, that what an integral domain is possibly missing is multiplicative inverses before it becomes a field. So we actually have to supply those two an integral domain that is not already a field in order to turn it into a field. In the case of $\mathbb Z,\mathbb Q$ we have for instance
$$
\{2,3,7\}\subset\mathbb Z
$$
but the multiplicative inverses $\{2^{-1},3^{-1},7^{-1}\}$ are missing. So we have to extend $\mathbb Z$ with those, hence for all $x\in\mathbb Z$ we must add $x^{-1}$ and form the smallest possible ring we can from that at the very least, before we can make any hope to have a field. In the case of the integral domain $\mathbb Z$ the field of fractions is (up to isomorphism) $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no paradox. The set of integers is a subset of the set of rationals, and the set of all fields is a subset of the set of all integral domains. (I don't want to irritate set theorists, so you can say the second fact just means every field is an integral domain.) The latter does not mean the set of rationals is a subset of the set of integers.

Answer (score 1):

The "paradox" you have discovered is because the integers are a subset of the rationals when you consider the elements themselves. Clearly all the members of the integers belong in the rationals, and the rationals are an extension of the integers themselves (a fraction field).

But as an algebraic structure, a field is less general than an integral domain. An integral domain has less restrictions on it than a field does (namely it lacks the requirement that its multiplicative monoid be an abelian group). So as a structure, fields can be seen as a "subset" of integral domains, but when you're dealing with specific examples you are brought back to actual set theory and such "paradoxes" might occur.

Comment: Good answer. I can digest better your "proletarian" explanation. Thanks.